# Debugging Laravel jobs

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I am trying to debug jobs on a queue in Laravel but to no success. I want to print output into the console. Such as how you use `dd()` everywhere else.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Image;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class ProcessImage implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $image;

    /**
     * Attempt the job a maximum of twice
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 2;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Image $image)
    {

        $this->image = $image;

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // set paths for standard and thumbnail size images

        $image          = public_path("assets" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->image->original);
        $product_id     = $this->image->id;
        $product_path   = public_path("assets" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "images" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
            "products" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product_id);


        $thumbnail_path = $product_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "thumbnail";

        if(!is_dir($product_path))
            mkdir($product_path);

        if(!is_dir($thumbnail_path))
            mkdir($thumbnail_path);

        // Resize and save the standard image

        $standard = \Image::make($image)->resize(450, 450, function($constraint)
        {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($product_path);

        dd($standard);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to debug the code you will need to assemble your command string that starts artisan accordingly like so - php -dxdebug.remote_autostart=1 artisan queue:work <queue_name> (source: https://medium.com/@kebing.yu/make-xdebug-work-with-laravel-queue-b5e73e44a36b)

Comment: use Laravel telescope

Answer (score 23):

1. Run `php artisan queue:restart` - if you're running queue as a daemon, you need to restart listener every time your code changes as the daemon loads code into memory.
2. `dump()`, `dd()`, and `Log::info()` should be working in queues. Make sure you debug gradually - log at the very beginning of job, then a little lower, lower still, etc. and see what's the last point you get logged out.
3. The output from `dump()` and `dd()` in queued tasks is sent to `storage/logs/worker.log`. `Log::info()` output is sent to the usual log at `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: Seems that it is getting logged in storage/logs, however I would expect a way to output to the console while the job is running, I assumed it would be based upon console.

Comment: How are you running your queue listener? `php artisan queue:work`? What parameters are you passing?

Comment: If you are using sail : `sail php artisan queue:restart`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to debug Laravel Job with PHP Storm edit `.env` file:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Put a breakpoint in the `handle()` function.

Answer (score 6):

you don't need to print it on the console.
full description of fail job is store in the exception column.(table name fail_jobs).
[image]

Comment: Mine was empty despite having spent days of purposely failing and debugging the jobs, so this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is I Log information that needs to be seen, like in your case:

```
\Log::info('Making new directory');
```

Or

```
\Log::info('this is new image: ', [$standard]);
```

and so on. just open the log info and see where the code breaks or the condition that should be working didn't work.

Comment: I have tried this, however I don't get any output. https://i.imgur.com/QvMwGE6.png

Comment: Yes there are Muhammad

Comment: This won't output in the log file.

Comment: Will you please explain why this will not work? @Shah-Kodes

Comment: Worked for me in case if you use the sync driver.
See `'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync')` line in queue.php file

Comment: Outputted to Laravel log file fine for me on Laravel 8 with the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

I use print_r() which can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in two ways:

1. Using `Cache` facade with method `put()`. And next, you can get this with `Cache::get($cacheKey);`. Here I can pass any data type: **Collections**, **arrays**, **integer**, **string**, etc.
2. Using `Log` facade with method `debug()`. The First parameter is the message and the second is context **only with array type**.

The first variant is easier for debugging various data, but the second is easier for getting debug info. I prefer the first variant :)